# How do I create a vector which replaces all values with NAs and NAs with a certain value in R

Tags: r

I have an existing vector with some NAs within it and I want to create another vector based on this with the NAs replace with a certain value and all the existing values replaced with NAs, how do I get around it?

Answer (score 0):

It's useful to give some background on your question, and usually a sample set of data causing the problem.

Here is one solution using a dummy value that won't be in your vector:

```
x <- c(0, 1, 2, NA, 4, 5)
[1]  0  1  2 NA  4  

x[is.na(x)]      <- 9999999 # Pick a value not in your vector
x[!x == 9999999] <- NA 
x[x == 9999999]  <- 50

[1] NA NA NA 50 NA NA
```

TC

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you had a vector and a certain value:

```
MyVector <- sample(c(NA,1:3),10,TRUE)
MyVector
# [1]  2 NA NA  3 NA  3 NA  3  2 NA
CertainValue <- 500
```

You might create a copy and use `[`:

```
AnotherVector <- MyVector
AnotherVector[is.na(MyVector)] <- CertainValue
AnotherVector[!is.na(MyVector)] <- NA
AnotherVector
# [1]  NA 500 500  NA 500  NA 500  NA  NA 500
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually very simple and there are multiple ways to do it in R. For example assuming `vec` is your vector and `replacement_value` is the value you want to replace your NAs with you can do it like this:

```
nas = is.na(vec);
vec[nas] = replacement_value;
vec[!nas] = NA;
rm(nas);
```

But honestly unless it is the only thing you are going to need R for in the near future I would recommend to read some book on the topic or at least have a glance at http://www.cookbook-r.com/ or some other general R guide. Going on without it is going to be so painfully slow that you will just hate it.